# Extracting document content using Apache Tika and Cloudera Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-tika

I'm trying to extract content from document using Apache Tika jar 1.6 and  running MapReduce job using CDH4.6. I have used the code form the below link

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chennaihug/waobSlV0-AE

But when I run the code following error is thrown

```
14/11/12 17:14:55 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201411121354_0007_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at TikaFileInputFormat.createRecordReader(TikaFileInputFormat.java:15)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:644)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you've neglected to push the Tika Jars out to your hadoop nodes. How are you deploying your code?

Comment: hadoop jar tikamap.jar TikaMapreduce file.pdf /output
Like this

Comment: And does `tikamap.jar` include all the tika jars + dependencies inside it?

Comment: Yes it includes all the dependencies

Comment: How ar!e you including them? Only the stacktrace you have posted seems to indicate that your hadoop mapper node thinks it doesn't have the dependencies it wants

Comment: I've included all dependencies while creating jar from eclipse IDE.

Comment: Edit your question to show how you did that, you may have missed something there